# Javascript Regular Expressions Email Address

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a homework assignment that I have completed. But I can not get the email address to test correctly. From what I can tell everything is correct.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lab 5, Part 3</title>
<script>
function validate()
{
var email = document.forms["form1"]["email"].value;
var emailValidator = "/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)+@\w+([\.:]?\w+)+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})+$/";

if (!email.match(emailValidator))
{
 alert("Not a valid Email Address");
 return false;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="text-align:center">Lab 5, Part 3 for </h1>
<h2 style="text-align:center">IT 3203</h2>

<form name="form1" action="http://weblab.kennesaw.edu/formtest.php" onsubmit="return validate();" method="get">
<p> Email: <input type="text" id="email" name="email"></p>
     <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p><a href=index.html>Back to Main Page</a></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: @nilobarp Flagged as duplicate.

Comment: *"From what I can tell everything is correct."* If it was then it would work, wouldn't it? :) So no, it's not. You somehow mixed the syntax of string literals and regex literals. Learn about regular expressions here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions .

Comment: Your regular expression should test for exactly this:

One or more word characters
Exactly one at-sign
One or more word characters
Exactly one period
Two or more characters that are a-z, A-Z, 0-9, period, or hyphen (One way to get "two or more" is to look for one such character and then look for one or more. Don't forget about character classes.)

This is the question presented

Comment: I think it was my "" around the syntax var emailValidator = "/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)+@\w+([\.:]?\w+)+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})+$/";

should be var emailValidator = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)+@\w+([\.:]?\w+)+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})+$/;

Comment: That's what I said in my answer, yes ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you some mixed string literal and regex literal notations:

```
"/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)+@\w+([\.:]?\w+)+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})+$/"
```

`"..."` denotes a string literal, `/.../` denotes a regex literal. While you can pass a string literal to `String#match`, the whole content of the string will be interpreted as the regex pattern. That means, given the above string, your code will only match of the test string literally contains `/^....`, which it doesn't.

Either use a string literal without the regex delimiters **and** escape all backslashes:

```
"^\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)+@\\w+([\\.:]?\w+)+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})+$"
```

or use a regex literal (preferable):

```
/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)+@\w+([\.:]?\w+)+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})+$/
```

[Have a look at MDN to learn more about regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: Appreciate the help ;)

Comment: A correction, it should be "^\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)+@\\w+([\\.:]?\\w+)+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})+$" not "^\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)+@\\w+([\\.:]?\w+)+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})+$" (a slash is missed)

Answer (score 0):

your code with correct regex
**var emailValidator = /^\w+[\w-+.]*\@\w+([-.]\w+)*.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lab 5, Part 3</title>
<script>
function validate()
{
var email = document.forms["form1"]["email"].value;
var emailValidator = /^\w+[\w-+\.]*\@\w+([-\.]\w+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;;

if (!email.match(emailValidator))
{
    alert("Not a valid Email Address");
    return false;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="text-align:center">Lab 5, Part 3 for </h1>
<h2 style="text-align:center">IT 3203</h2>

<form name="form1" action="http://weblab.kennesaw.edu/formtest.php" onsubmit="return validate();" method="get">
<p> Email: <input type="text" id="email" name="email"></p>
           <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p><a href=index.html>Back to Main Page</a></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Email validator rules,

```
function validate()
{
    var email = document.forms["form1"]["email"].value;

    var emailValidator = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

    if (!email.match(emailValidator))
    {
        alert("Not a valid Email Address");
        return false;
    }else{
        alert("Correct Email Address");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Your Email Validator rule was not in well formed. Give the valid regular expression rules.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Lab 5, Part 3</title>
 <script>
 function validate()
 {
  var email = document.forms["form1"]["email"].value;
  var emailValidator = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

  if (!email.match(emailValidator))
  {
   alert("Not a valid Email Address");
   return false;
  }else{
   alert("This is a Valid Email Address");
   return true;
  }
 }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <h1 style="text-align:center">Lab 5, Part 3 for </h1>
 <h2 style="text-align:center">IT 3203</h2>

 <form name="form1" action="http://weblab.kennesaw.edu/formtest.php" onsubmit="return validate();" method="get">
  <p> Email: <input type="text" id="email" name="email"></p>
  <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
 </form>

 <p><a href=index.html>Back to Main Page</a></p>


</body>
</html>
```